# Possessive pronoun and object

Tags: possessives

Definition of ***their***: of or relating to them or themselves especially as possessors, agents, or **objects** of an action

If I assist *them*, can I say ***their assistance*** (as object of an action)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speak of 'going to their assistance' meaning 'going to help them'.

Comment: Technically, can I say ‘thank you for my help’ instead of ‘thank you for your help’ to express I thank you for your helping me?

Comment: No, you can't. _[Go] to someone's assistance_ is idiomatic, but in other expressions it's always _giving **your** help/assistance **to** them_.

Answer (score 0):

> :Q. If I assist them, can I say ‘their assistance’ (object of an action)?

A. No, the sentence makes no sense.

*If you assist them you would be their **assistant***